# $\log_{10}2 ≈ 0.30103$, find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the decimal representation of $2^{10n}$ does not begin with the digit $1$.

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, solution-verification, integers

> **QUESTION:** Given that $\log_{10}2 ≈ 0.30103$, find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the decimal representation of $2^{10n}$ does not begin with the digit $1$.

---

**MY ANSWER:** Let $$2^{10n}=z$$ $$\implies 10n\text{ } \log_{\small{10}}2=\log_{\small{10}}z$$ $$\implies \log_{\small{10}}z=3.0103n$$ $$\therefore z=10^{3.0103n}$$ Now we known that $a^{\log b}=b^{\log{a}}$

We assume that $3.0103n=\log_{\small{10}}x$ $$\implies z=x^{\log_{\small{10}}10}$$ $$\text{or, } z=x$$ According to the given condition $x$ must not start with $1$. Therefore $x\geq{2}$.. $(x\nless{1}, \because n \in \Bbb{Z^+})$

$$\therefore n\geq{\frac{\log_{\small{10}}2}{3.0103}}$$ $$\implies n\geq{\frac{0.30103}{3.0103}}=\frac{1}{10}$$ $\because n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ $\therefore$ the smallest $n$ is $1$. But clearly $1$ does not satisfy the given condition $(2^{10}=1024)$..

> Where am I possibly going wrong? Thank You for your help in advance.. :)

Comment: You appear to assert that, for any integer $k≥2$, we know that $k$ does not begin with $1$.  This is not true.

Comment: @lulu Oh yes! I see.. You mean to say that for digits like $13$... if $x=13$ then $z=10^{log_{\small{10}}13}$, $\implies z=13^{log_{\small{10}}10}=13$, does not satisfy our condition.. That was so stupid of me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the request for the leading digit you can disregard all integer powers of 10. Thus decompose
$$
2^{10n}\approx 10^{3n}\cdot 10^{0.0103n}.
$$
It is the second factor now that determines the leading digit. So you want to know when
$$
10^{0.0103n}\ge 2=10^{0.30103}\\~\\
n\ge\frac{0.30103}{0.0103}=\frac{30.103}{1.03}=29.22621..
$$
giving $n=30$. It seems unlikely that reducing rounding/truncation errors will change that result.

Comment: I got you.. Thank you so much.. But a very different doubt suddenly peeps in my mind now... When you break down $10^{3.0103n}$ into $10^{3n}$ and $10^{0.0103n}$ you get the answer as $30$ but when I use the full thing I get $1$, wayyy less than $30$... Leaving apart the calculations, shouldn't have I got more than $30$?

Comment: You want to explore the leading digit, and that is given as the integer part of $10^{0.0103n}$. This decomposition is valid as long as $0.0103n<1$.